# Three JS - Join 2 CubicBezierCurve3's together with smooth join?

Tags: typescript, three.js

I have a scene with 6 objects around a centre object (centre object v3: 0,0,0). The camera is placed behind and above one object and is looking at the centre.

I have used a CubicBezierCurve3 to plot a curve from the camera's existing position (behind and above one object), towards another 'clicked' object, and ending at the same relative position as before (behind and above the 'clicked' object and looking towards centre).

It currently works fine, yet I've been tasked with using 2 bezier curves to plot the camera's movement, where the endpoint of the first curve is shared as the start point for the second curve. To create a smooth join, the 2nd control point of bez1 and the 1st control point of bez2 need to be of equal angle and distance in opposite directions.

I have the direction of bez1-c2 to bez1-end and assumed I could multiply this to pop bez2-c1 in the opposite position, yet it breaks off to a slight angle...

Has anyone done this before or can direct me somewhere for help/example?

Thanks

EDIT:

```
    const objectVector = this.lastClickedObjectPos.clone();

    const bezier1StartPoint = this._camera.position.clone();

    const dirFromSunToCamera = new Vector3(0, 0, 0).sub(bezier1StartPoint);
    const distanceFromSunToCamera: number = new Vector3(0, 0, 0).distanceTo(bezier1StartPoint);

    const dirFromSunToObject = objectVector.clone().sub(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
    const distanceFromSunToObject: number = new Vector3(0, 0, 0).distanceTo(objectVector);

    const bezier2EndPoint = dirFromSunToObject.normalize().multiplyScalar(distanceFromSunToObject * 2);
    bezier2EndPoint.y += bezier1StartPoint.y;

    const dirFromSunToEnd = new Vector3(0, 0, 0).sub(bezier2EndPoint);

    const bezier1ControlPoint1 = dirFromSunToCamera
        .clone()
        .normalize()
        .multiplyScalar(distanceFromSunToCamera * -0.5);

    const dirFromBez1StartToBez2End = bezier1StartPoint.clone().sub(bezier2EndPoint);

    const bezier2StartPoint = dirFromBez1StartToBez2End.clone().normalize();

    const dirFromBez1StartToBez1End = bezier1StartPoint.clone().sub(bezier1EndPoint);
    const distanceBez1StartToBez1End = bezier1StartPoint.distanceTo(bezier1EndPoint);

    const bezier1ControlPoint2 = dirFromBez1StartToBez1End
        .clone()
        .normalize()
        .multiplyScalar(distanceBez1StartToBez1End * 0.5);

    const dirFromBez1Control2ToBez1End = bezier1StartPoint.clone().sub(bezier1ControlPoint2);
    const distanceBez1Control2ToBez1End = bezier1ControlPoint2.distanceTo(bezier1EndPoint);

    const bezier2ControlPoint1 = dirFromBez1Control2ToBez1End
        .clone()
        .normalize()
        .multiplyScalar(distanceBez1Control2ToBez1End * -2);

    const bezier2ControlPoint2 = dirFromSunToEnd
        .clone()
        .normalize()
        .multiplyScalar(distanceFromSunToObject * -6);
```

Sorry if the code's funky, but it's the bezier1ControlPoint2 and bezier2ControlPoint1 where the issue is. The scene's representing a solar system type thing, where the Sun is the 'centre' i.e. v3(0,0,0).

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please, read about [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, I've included the snippet I'm working in